# Pusher not working, no push notifications, is echo working at all?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, broadcast, pusher

I followed this tutorial to understand how to implement realtime notifications:

https://www.sitepoint.com/add-real-time-notifications-laravel-pusher/

I set up the simple-blog new project as in the instructions and was able to make notifications work, however the last step, pusher, doesn't work. I also tried to clone the entire repo thinking maybe I was making some mistake in code but it doesn't work either. Of course I set up my pusher app and put keys etc in .env and in javascript. Can anyone try to clone that and see if it's working? I can't seem to find what the problem is here.

I already tried to start the queue with `php artisan queue:work` and `php artisan queue:listen`

This is the channel route:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class`, in config/app.php is set

I don't know why it's not working.
Any clue?

Comment: What version of Laravel? Is your `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` in your .env?

Comment: Yes , that was the deal. It was set to log

Comment: Yup, I've had that same issue before :), I've gone ahead and put that as an answer to help any others too. @Chriz74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set your `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` in your .env